# Как задать шаблон строки в поле таблицы T-SQL?

Tags: sql, регулярные-выражения, sql-server

Мне нужно, чтобы значение в определенном поле таблицы удовлетворяло шаблону. Я пытался сделать что-то вроде следующего.

```
CREATE TABLE std(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    tel CHAR(8) NOT NULL LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
);
```

Нужно, чтобы в поле tel можно было содержать только значения вида xx-xx-xx, где x - любая цифра. Такую проверку нужно сделать именно при создании таблицы, в запросах не пойдет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался.
Нужно просто завернуть условие в CHECK.

```
tel CHAR(8) NOT NULL CHECK (tel LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]')
```